# Product Image Preview in Admin Not Displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

Product Image Preview in Admin Not Displaying Anymore , i get to an unknown text. any suggested for this problem ?.

[image]

Comment: in which browser you are checking this?  Check your browser flash player is up to date

Comment: @ShaheerAli , i have latest version installed

Comment: did you check this also in other browsers and you updated the varsion of your magento?

Comment: i've check this also in another browser, my Magento version is 1.9.2.1

Comment: check console log for any js error and did you install any module ?

Comment: No any js error in log console , but i've update my local server ( MAMP ) and this problem appear after this update.